# how do i create a carousel that slides on next and previous button click, the carousel should switch divs and not images

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, carousel

i want a slide effect that switches between divs on a click of a button, next and previous

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div>slide 1</div>
        <div>slide 2</div>
        <div>slide 3</div>
        <div>slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
</div>
```

deleted most of the codes i tried.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div>slide 1</div>
        <div>slide 2</div>
        <div>slide 3</div>
        <div>slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials for this stuff. What have you already tried and what problems do you have?

Comment: most tutorials i have seen are implemented with images, what I want is a div carousel, where you switch between hidden divs not images

Comment: The code of the tutorials with images is the same as for using divs

Comment: Pls if you have any examples, do well to share with me

Comment: This question clearly lacks basic research and has no clear coding issue. It looks like a code request. You will find a bunch of examples [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+carousel+div+%22example%22) a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you have images or divs. The mechanism is the same. You basically set initial active slide and create functions to go to previous or next slide. Every time you need to check if active slide is the first/last slide.

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel div")
const firstSlide = 0
const lastSlide = slides.length - 1
let activeSlide = 0

const goToPreviousSlide = () => {
  slides[activeSlide].classList.remove("active")
  if (activeSlide !== firstSlide) {
    activeSlide = activeSlide - 1
  } else {
    activeSlide = lastSlide
  }
  slides[activeSlide].classList.add("active")
}

const goToNextSlide = () => {
  slides[activeSlide].classList.remove("active")
  if (activeSlide !== lastSlide) {
    activeSlide = activeSlide + 1
  } else {
    activeSlide = firstSlide
  }
  slides[activeSlide].classList.add("active")
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.carousel {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.carousel div {
  display: none;
}
.carousel div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button onclick="goToPreviousSlide()">Previous</button>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="active">slide 1</div>
        <div>slide 2</div>
        <div>slide 3</div>
        <div>slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="goToNextSlide()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was doing a wrong implementation.

Comment: Can i make the transition smooth and make it slide automatically

Comment: Sure. You can for example add `overflow: hidden;` to your `.carousel` container. And then use CSS animations to move current and next slides from left to right or vice versa